# Oracle SQL when to use the full hint

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I understand that the full hint:

```
/*+ FULL(alias) */
```

will force the optimizer to perform a full table scan.

Are there any scenarios where this would be more useful than using an index besides the obvious one where the query selects the majority of the rows in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very wide topic.

From Oracle documentation `"When using hints, in some cases, you might need to specify a full set of hints in order to ensure the optimal execution plan. For example, if you have a very complex query, which consists of many table joins, and if you specify only the INDEX hint for a given table, then the optimizer needs to determine the remaining access paths to be used, as well as the corresponding join methods. Therefore, even though you gave the INDEX hint, the optimizer might not necessarily use that hint, because the optimizer might have determined that the requested index cannot be used due to the join methods and access paths selected by the optimizer."`

It avoids indexes and go for a FTS.

This has exceptions, like all general concepts. A full table scan can be less expensive than an index scan followed by table access by rowid - sometimes much less expensive.

An excerpt [from](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/why-does-my-query-run-faster-after-i-force-full-table-scan):

Index blocks need to be read too, in addition to the table's blocks. If the index is large (a sizable percentage of the table's size), the pressure on the SGA (and associates latches) might be noticeable
If the sort order of the index doesn't match the way the data is stored in the actual table, the number of logical I/Os necessary to fulfill the query could be (potentially much) more than the number of LIOs to do the full table scan. (The index's clustering factor is one of the indicators you can look at to estimate this.)

Essentially, if scanning via your index makes the data block I/O requests jump all over your table, the overall cost is going to be higher than if you could do large sequential reads. An FTS is more likely to use multi-block direct-path reads, bypassing the SGA entirely, which is also potentially good - no "cache thrashing", less latching.

If you have a covering index, chances are that's going to beat a full table scan all the time. If not, it's going to depend on what percentage of actual blocks (data + index) will need to be processed (the index's selectivity for that query), and how well they're "physically sorted" with respect to each-other.

As to why the optimizer is picking the "wrong" path for you here: hard to tell. Stale statistics on the index or table could be an issue like always, the estimate calculated base on the LIKE might be off for certain patterns, instance parameters could favor indexes a bit too much, ... If this is the only query that's misbehaving, and your stats are up to date, using a /*+ full */ hint doesn't sound too bad.

Also read Stack [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170915130327/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1490/hints)